# How to use my own fork of flutter in `pubspec.yaml`

Tags: flutter, dart, github, cicd, pubspec

I need to change some parts of the original flutter code in my project. I know that I can do so in my local copy. However, we are working as a group and I don't want my changes to be local.

Also, we will probably use GitHub actions for CD. If I only change my local copy of the flutter source code, the executable/app generated by the CD won't match what I'm locally building.

***In short, the problem:*** having GitHub CI/CD to match my local setup, and all participants in the project to share the same code-base and dependencies, with a custom fork of flutter present.

Is there any way to provide my own fork of flutter to the `pubspec.yaml` file? Or are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious... what kind of thing have you changed?  Is there an issue you can reference here? Have you submitted a pull request?

Comment: I've changed cupertino switch's thumb size from `14.0` to `12.0`, it looks much nicer for our design. I've searched for this in the github issues, saw nothing related to it. I guess they will not accept the PR because cupertino is supposedly obey the iOS design, in a strict manner (I mean, even a configurable thumb size would be against the iOS design I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to fork the flutter repo, make your changes, and then publish your fork for your teammates to access. Then they would have to `git clone` your fork and use that as their local flutter installation to build the project.

There is no way to do this in `pubspec.yaml`. You can set flutter version constraints for when you are developing packages in the `pubspec.yaml`, but that is not what you are trying to do here.

Perhaps it would be worth taking a look at another solution. I am not sure what you modified, but instead of modifying whatever you did directly, how about you copy all of the relevant source code into your own project (I'm guessing a widget), modify the code in your project, and then reference your own custom code instead of Flutter's version?

Comment: I see, so there is no way to tell github actions to use my fork of flutter in the CD. I actually modified the thumb size of the cupertino switch. So maybe a better approach would be somehow extract the cupertino switch as a separate package, upload it to github, and have a dependency to it in the `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Didn't see your tidbit on CI/CD before--you can set your CI/CD to use your own custom fork of flutter. I am guessing you are using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/flutter-action. I don't see any support for custom forks on this action at first glance, but you could fork the action and then have it point to your own Flutter fork. However; you should do as you described: extract the Cupertino switch, make your changes, upload as a separate package to Github, and then reference that in your pubspec.yaml.